# How can ı do scrolltop with jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<div class="logo-contentBlock"> 
   <a href="#logo-first-content" class="content-page-scroll-1">BLOG</a>
</div>
<div class="logo-contentBlock"> 
   <a href="#logo-second-content" class="content-page-scroll-2">BLOG</a>
</div>
   .
   .
   .
  <div id="#logo-first-content">.....</div>
  <div id="#logo-second-content">....</div>




$(".content-page-scroll-1").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#content-first-content').offset().top - 60
    },5000);
});
$(".content-page-scroll-2").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#content-second-content').offset().top - 60
    }, 5000);
});
$(".content-page-scroll-3").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#logo-thirt-content').offset().top - 60
    }, 5000);
});
```

Hello, ı just want scrolltop 60 but ı have 9 content like that that means a lot of jquery. How can i do shorten my code with jquery?

Answer (score 1):

The thing to notice here is that the only thing changing between the callbacks is the CSS-selector. To stay [*DRY*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) here, I would define a function that takes a CSS-selector and returns the click-handler.

Working off your example, for example like so:

```
const cbFactory = selector => () => {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(selector).offset().top - 60
    },5000);
};

$(".content-page-scroll-1").click(cbFactory('#content-first-content'));
$(".content-page-scroll-2").click(cbFactory('#content-second-content'));
$(".content-page-scroll-3").click(cbFactory('#logo-thirt-content'));
```